# What were the historical theories of price formation before demand-supply relationship was well understood?

Tags: supply-and-demand, price, history-economic-thought, economic-history, price-theory

Markets have existed for thousands of years. People must had ideas about where prices came from.

Before the clear formulation of demand/supply-based theory of prices, what were the historical theories of price formation?